# how to create a utf-8 character string using string constructor?

Tags: c++

I need to create a utf-8 character string using the string constructor. For this I tried:

```
string(size,u8'\u2500');
wstring(size,u8'\u2500');
u8string(size,u8'\u2500');
```

But every time gcc produces:

> error:character constant too long for its type

- there is an additional question. What is the difference between u8string and wstring?

Comment: A wstring is backed by wchar_t.  A u8string is backed by char8_t.  `u2500` is `0xE2 0x94 0x80`, which is too big to fit in a single char, or single char8_t, and probably inappropriate for wchar_t.

Comment: A `u8` character was a single `char` before the C++20 standard, after it's a [`char8_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#char8_t) character. It's big enough for a single UTF-8 *code unit*, which is 8 bits. You can't store a multi-byte UTF-8 code point in it. For that you need an actual string, like `u8"\u2500"` (or just plain `"\u2500"`).

Comment: 8 in `u8` stands for the number of bits. How do you plan to fit a number having 4 hexadecimal digits into one of those? You cannot. Try `"\u2500"` (note double quotes; try with or without `u8` prefix).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI those. There is no way I can put \u2500 into 1 character so that I can then use the string constructor?

Comment: Yes, there are no way how you can put 3 bytes into single byte. Why it is surprising?

Comment: Utf-8 is mutibyte encoding with variable size. As a result there is no `char`-like type to store Utf-8 character. You have to store this in `std::string` or `std::u8strrint` and use a string literal, not a character literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 support in C++20 still leaves a lot to be desired.

Here is some code that adds a (somewhat silly) `operator*` to repeat a string, and use that to cobble together a 10 character long `u2500` character (which is encoded as 3 char8_t encoding units).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::size_t;
using std::u8string;

namespace {

auto operator*(u8string const& u, size_t s) {
    u8string result;
    result.reserve(u.size() * s); // Thanks Bathsheba!

    for (size_t i{}; i < s; ++i) {
        result += u;
    }

    return result;
}

auto operator<<(ostream& out, u8string const& u) -> ostream& {
    auto text{ reinterpret_cast<char const*>(u.c_str()) };
    return out << text;
}

} // anon

int main() {
    size_t size = 10;
    u8string u2500{ u8"\u2500" };
    u8string u{ u2500 * size };
    cout << u << "\n";
}
```

Comment: A call to `reserve` would prevent memory reallocations - the final length is known.